# Who has deleted files in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Which is the best way to find out who deleted files in AWS S3 bucket?

I am working on AWS S3 Bucket. Going through the AWS docs and haven't found the best way to monitor S3 buckets so thought of checking if anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 2):

For monitoring S3 object operations, such as `DeleteObject`, you have to enable [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-concepts.html#cloudtrail-concepts-trails) with S3 data events:

- [How do I enable object-level logging for an S3 bucket with AWS CloudTrail data events?](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html)
- [Examples: Logging Data Events for Amazon S3 Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#logging-data-events-examples)

However, the trials **don't work retrospectively**. Thus, you have to check if you have such trial enabled in CloudTrail console. If not, then you can create one to monitor any future S3 object level activities for all, or selected, buckets.

To reduce the impact of accidental deletions you can enable [object version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html). And to fully protect against that for important objects, you can use [MFA delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete).

Answer (score 0):

You can check S3 access logs or CloudTrail to check who deleted files from your S3 bucket. More information here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-audit-deleted-missing-objects/